# enums - assigning values to constants

Tags: apex

How can I accomplish the following in apex?

```
public enum MathEnum{
  Decimal PI = 3.14,
  ....
}
```

I need to assign values to the constants in an enum.

Comment: You can't do it in apex. If you want to access PI number, use `Math.PI` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apex enums are very basic with only the name and an ordinal value available as listed in [Enum Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_enum.htm). So you cannot directly attach other data such as a Decimal value.

Instead you can use simple constants such as:

```
public class Maths {
    public static final Decimal PI = 3.1416;
}
```

Or you can simulate a richer enum by using the old type-safe enum coding pattern that has largely been replaced in Java by the current rich enum feature. That would look something like this:

```
public class MathEnum {

    // All the enum values
    public static MathEnum[] values {get; private set;}
    static {
        values = new MathEnum[] {};
    }

    // Specific enum values
    public static MathEnum PI = new MathEnum('PI', 3.1416);
    public static MathEnum E = new MathEnum('E', 2.7183);

    // Data values available on each enum
    public String name {get; private set;}
    public Decimal value {get; private set;}

    private MathEnum(String name, Decimal value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        values.add(this);
    }

    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceOf MathEnum) {
            MathEnum that = (MathEnum) o;
            return this.name == that.name;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Integer hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

and of course additional field values can be added.

Comment: @Cubancoffee You are welcome. We use the type-safe enum technique in quite a few places in our code base and it makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Pickayune comment --  I can't change the one character here, but pi is ~ 3.1415926, so 3.1416 to your degree of precision, not 3.1414.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Thanks - sloppy of me, changed now. I added an extra digit to E too to match a bit better.